# filtering ECG, only keep QRS complex

Tags: matlab, filter

Hi there (all researchers, experts, students .... likeWise)
I am Tursun and Im new here. 
I have an ECG signal like this:

If we magnify, it looks like this:

I have a code it can show 3 peaks in QRS like this:
[QRS peaks I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnYM4.png)
As you can see, peaks found are not so correct (missing real peaks in the middle especially).
Surly, more filtering/smoothing signal solve this problem. my SGolay filter

```
 smoothECG = sgolayfilt(mySignal,1,41);
```

results this:

However somebody states in his PhD thesis that frequency range of QRS complex is 10-40 Hz :

I want to use filter to keep QRS complex, and eliminate all other peaks and allies in ECG signal, like this (illustration):
[a filter I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uy3C.png)
I found that normal bandpass filter created by "fdatool" does not do above job.
It would be great if somebody teach me HOW?

(my peak detection code matlab is modified from matlab peak analysis:

Comment: welcome! most people wont know what an ecg is, so i would write the whole word a refer to it as heartsignal. a bandpass filter might be part of what you want but wont do the entire job. could you please provide your code so far and some sample signals? espacially the signals would be really important

Comment: @Finn,I wanted to add link to download my ECG/heart signal and a code. But adding link requires 1500 reputation points which I do not have. my signal is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lijszlrz8cereb2/mySignal.mat?dl=0, you can omit the need of finding peaks for the time being. flattening all parts except QRS complex is important. Thank you @ Finn

Comment: is the question still open?

Comment: @Finn, please feel free to share your idea!